# "Broken pipe" E_NOTICE during PHP shutdown, stale data on a closed socket?

Tags: php, php-7

PHP 7.2 app, with a MySQL database. There's a custom error handler set via `set_error_handler`. On the prod site, ever once in a while, it receives an E_NOTICE notification with the following error string:

> Unknown: send of 5 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe

The file:line of the notification is Unknown:0.

There's no **higher level error** to correlate this with. There's no file/line either. The `debug_backtrace()` is empty. I know the startup script name for those cases (it's a CRON-run scheduled command line PHP script), but that gives me almost nothing.

I saw similar errors from MySQL operations where the server would go away after a timeout (MySQL error 2006), but in those cases, there'd also be an error from `query()` or `ping()`. Not so in this case.

The error looks like a socket error; other than MySQL, this script uses cURL to hit a REST endpoint. But there are no cURL errors that I can see.

Any ideas how can I trace this back to the offending line, short of bad old `printf` debugging?

EDIT: I've tracked it down to an error handler that uses [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/) to send an e-mail via SMTP. That library uses sockets, so the link to `streams/xp_socket.c` is on to something.

HOWEVER, the notice happens **after** the `PHPMailer::send()` function returns, during (or after) the exit() call. Looks like there's some unsent data from the socket operations that PHP flushes during shutdown, and fails. However, the only socket that I can see is closed during the destruction of the PHPMailer object.

Could there be some stale state on the closed socket?

Comment: The only occurence of this error message is in `php_sockop_write()` of `main/streams/xp_socket.c`, which I don't think any mysql driver uses.

Comment: *Maybe* those notices were *interspersed* with "MySQL has gone away" errors, not correlated. Hard to tell, with no error location.

Comment: The *Unknown:0* location would usually indicate startup errors. But that doesn't make sense when it got captured in a runtime error handler. Anyway, a cumbersome way to investigate: `raise (SIGABRT);` patched into the streams error handler, then `gdb` on the coredump to investigate the callstack. It's probably going to be something dull...

Comment: Hm, I see if the coredump will be where I can see it. It's a shared prod server that I don't run.

Comment: It's not a startup error, it's a *shutdown* error. Some kind of stale state cleanup (but not a global PHP object destructor).